# Check if form has at least one filled / checked / selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if at least one of form's items has been filled / checked / selected. Form uses input fields, checkboxes and radio buttons. At least one of the items should be selected / filled / checked for the form to proceed.

My solution is the following:

```
$('#subform').submit(function(e){

  els = $('.filter_ext[type="text"], .filter_ext[type="radio"]:checked, .filter_ext[type="checkbox"], select.filter_ext');
  empty_count = 0;

  els.each(function(){
    th = $(this);
    cur_val = th.val();

    if(cur_val=='' || !th.checked) {
      th.prop('disabled', true); // omit empty items from url get variables (nicer url)
      empty_count ++;
    }
  });

  if(empty_count == els.length) { // if all are empty stop form submit
    e.preventDefault();
  } // else proceed with submitting form

});
```

**Is there a more elegant way to solve this?**

**EDIT**
Thanks to [Louys Patrice Bessette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159528/louys-patrice-bessette)'s answer, I simplified with the following code (adding the disablement to his solution):

```
var serialized_orig = $('#subform').serialize();
$('#subform').submit(function(e){

  th = $(this);
  serialized = th.serialize();

  $.each(serialized.split('&'),function(i,v){

    item = v.split('=');
    item_name = item[0];
    item_value = item[1];

    if(item_value == '') {

      $('.filter_ext[name="'+item_name+'"]').prop('disabled', true);

    }

  });

  if(serialized == serialized_orig) {

    e.preventDefault();

  }

});
```

Comment: About working code improvement, look for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Or look for `required` in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, form validation will have a close look at **all required fields** to be filled... 
It is based on an **AND** logic...

Now, your question is something quite unusual:

> if at least one of form's items has been filled / checked / selected.

That is an **OR** logic!

So I came up with a funny idea...
What if on `submit`, you compare the serialised form data with an "original unfilled" one?

Just make sure to have a `name` attribute on each elements...

```js
// Original unfilled form data
var initialFormValues = $("#subform").serialize();

$("#subform").on("submit",function(e){
  if( $(this).serialize() == initialFormValues ){  // Is form data changed?
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Not submitted");
  }else{
    e.preventDefault();  // Just for that snippet! remove that for real.
    console.log("Submitted");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="subform">
  <input type="text" name = "text"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">2<br>
  <select name="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting solution :) I added my new code using your idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.some()` for detecting that at least one of the elements in the collection contains the condition. I wrote a vanilla JS example for you - feel free to evaluate it: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/ywoJxg

It'd look something like this in jQuery (not tested):

```
const isValid = $('.formElem').some(($elem) => $elem.val().length || $elem.attr('checked'));
```

Comment: jQuery objects do not have a `.some` method - you'd have to convert it to an array first for that. Also, OP needs to iterate through *all* selected elements regardless, so as to make them `disabled` if need be, so `.some` (which short-circuits) won't really work by itself - this just makes it so that the iteration runs twice, rather than just once